# Problema al Registar Usuario

Tags: java

En un trabajo para la uni no registra al usuario. La forma de comprobarlo es con un mensaje "Usuario añadido." Pero no he conseguido que funciones. Compila y no da muestra ningún error. He utilizado [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder) para la interfaz.

Adjunto el código de la interfaz y de la clase que gestiona los usuarios:

```
   import java.awt.EventQueue;
    
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
    import java.awt.Choice;
    
    public class Formulario {
        private GestorUsuarios gestor;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textFieldNombre;
    private JLabel lblPrimerApellido;
    private JLabel lblSegundoApellido;
    private JLabel lblTelefono;
    private JLabel lblDni;
    private JLabel lblEmail;
    private JLabel lblDireccion;
    private JLabel lblFechaNacimiento;
    private JLabel lblSexo;
    private JTextField textFieldApellido1;
    private JTextField textFieldApellido2;
    private JTextField textFieldTelefono;
    private JTextField textFieldDNI;
    private JTextField textFieldEmail;
    private JTextField textFieldDireccion;
    private JTextField textFieldDia;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnPremium;
    private JLabel lblTipo;
    private JLabel lblFacebook;
    private JLabel lblCuenta;
    private JLabel lblEstudios;
    private JLabel lblEstadoCivil;
    private JTextField textFieldFacebook;
    private JTextField textFieldCuenta;
    private JTextField textFieldEstudios;
    private JTextField textFieldEstadoCivil;
    private Choice choice;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_2;
    private JTextField textFieldMes;
    private JTextField textFieldAno;
    private JButton btnNewButtonRegistrar;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GestorUsuarios gestor = new GestorUsuarios();

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Formulario window = new Formulario(gestor);
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * 
     * @param gestor2
     */
    public Formulario(GestorUsuarios gestor) {
        this.gestor = gestor;
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 428, 591);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][][grow]", "[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]"));

        lblTipo = new JLabel("Tipo");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTipo, "cell 0 0,alignx left");

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Nombre*");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, "cell 0 1,alignx left");

        textFieldNombre = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldNombre, "cell 2 1,growx");
        textFieldNombre.setColumns(10);

        lblPrimerApellido = new JLabel("Primer Apellido");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPrimerApellido, "cell 0 2,alignx left");
        frame.setVisible(false);

        textFieldApellido1 = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldApellido1, "cell 2 2,growx");
        textFieldApellido1.setColumns(10);

        lblSegundoApellido = new JLabel("Segundo Apellido");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSegundoApellido, "cell 0 3,alignx left");

        textFieldApellido2 = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldApellido2, "cell 2 3,growx");
        textFieldApellido2.setColumns(10);

        lblTelefono = new JLabel("Telefono");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTelefono, "cell 0 4,alignx left");

        textFieldTelefono = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldTelefono, "cell 2 4,growx");
        textFieldTelefono.setColumns(10);

        lblDni = new JLabel("DNI");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDni, "cell 0 5,alignx left");

        textFieldDNI = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldDNI, "cell 2 5,growx");
        textFieldDNI.setColumns(10);

        lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEmail, "cell 0 6,alignx left");

        textFieldEmail = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldEmail, "cell 2 6,growx");
        textFieldEmail.setColumns(10);

        lblDireccion = new JLabel("Dirección");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDireccion, "cell 0 7,alignx left");

        textFieldDireccion = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldDireccion, "cell 2 7,growx");
        textFieldDireccion.setColumns(10);

        lblFechaNacimiento = new JLabel("Dia");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblFechaNacimiento, "cell 0 8,alignx left");

        textFieldDia = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldDia, "cell 2 8,growx");
        textFieldDia.setColumns(10);

        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Mes");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1, "cell 0 9");

        textFieldMes = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldMes, "cell 2 9,growx");
        textFieldMes.setColumns(10);

        lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Año");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2, "cell 0 10");

        textFieldAno = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldAno, "cell 2 10,growx");
        textFieldAno.setColumns(10);

        lblSexo = new JLabel("Sexo");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSexo, "cell 0 11,alignx left");

        rdbtnPremium = new JRadioButton("Premium");
        frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnPremium, "cell 2 0");
        rdbtnPremium.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textFieldFacebook.setEnabled(true);
                textFieldCuenta.setEnabled(true);
                textFieldEstudios.setEnabled(true);
                textFieldEstadoCivil.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        choice = new Choice();
        frame.getContentPane().add(choice, "cell 2 11");
        choice.add("Hombre");
        choice.add("Mujer");

        lblFacebook = new JLabel("Facebook");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblFacebook, "cell 0 12,alignx left");

        textFieldFacebook = new JTextField();
        textFieldFacebook.setEnabled(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldFacebook, "cell 2 12,growx");
        textFieldFacebook.setColumns(10);

        lblCuenta = new JLabel("Cuenta");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCuenta, "cell 0 13,alignx left");

        textFieldCuenta = new JTextField();
        textFieldCuenta.setEnabled(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldCuenta, "cell 2 13,growx");
        textFieldCuenta.setColumns(10);

        lblEstudios = new JLabel("Estudios");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEstudios, "cell 0 14,alignx left");

        textFieldEstudios = new JTextField();
        textFieldEstudios.setEnabled(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldEstudios, "cell 2 14,growx");
        textFieldEstudios.setColumns(10);

        lblEstadoCivil = new JLabel("Estado Civil");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEstadoCivil, "cell 0 15,alignx left");

        textFieldEstadoCivil = new JTextField();
        textFieldEstadoCivil.setEnabled(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldEstadoCivil, "cell 2 15,growx");
        textFieldEstadoCivil.setColumns(10);
        
        btnNewButtonRegistrar = new JButton("Registrar");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButtonRegistrar, "cell 0 17 3 1,growx");

        btnNewButtonRegistrar = new JButton("Registrar");
        btnNewButtonRegistrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int telefono = Integer.parseInt(textFieldTelefono.getText());
                int dia = Integer.parseInt(textFieldDia.getText());
                int mes = Integer.parseInt(textFieldMes.getText());
                int ano = Integer.parseInt(textFieldAno.getText());

                if (rdbtnPremium.isSelected()) {
                    Premium usuarioPremium = new Premium(
                            textFieldNombre.getText(), 
                            textFieldApellido1.getText(),
                            textFieldApellido2.getText(), 
                            textFieldDNI.getText(), textFieldEmail.getText(),
                            textFieldDireccion.getText(), 
                            dia, mes, ano, 
                            choice.getSelectedItem(),
                            textFieldCuenta.getText(), 
                            telefono, 
                            textFieldFacebook.getText(),
                            textFieldEstudios.getText(), 
                            textFieldEstadoCivil.getText());
                            
                            gestor.altaUsuario(usuarioPremium);
                } else {
                    Free usuarioFree = new Free(textFieldNombre.getText(), 
                            textFieldApellido1.getText(),
                            textFieldApellido2.getText(), 
                            telefono, 
                            textFieldDNI.getText(), 
                            textFieldEmail.getText(),
                            textFieldDireccion.getText(), 
                            dia, mes, ano, 
                            choice.getSelectedItem());
                    
                    gestor.altaUsuario(usuarioFree);
                    {

                    }
                }
                ;
            
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase que gestiona los usuarios:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class GestorUsuarios {

    private Vector<Free> usuarios;

    GestorUsuarios() { // Constructor
        this.usuarios = new Vector<Free>();
    }

    public void altaUsuario(Free usuario) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean registrado = false;

        while (i < this.usuarios.size() & !registrado) {
            if (this.usuarios.get(i).getDni().equals(usuario.getDni())) {
                registrado = true;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (registrado = false) {
            this.usuarios.add(usuario);
            System.out.println("Usuario añadido.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El usuario ya está registrado.");
        }

    }

    public void bajaUsuario(Free usuario) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean registrado = false;

        while (i < this.usuarios.size() & !registrado) {
            if (this.usuarios.get(i).getDni().equals(usuario.getDni())) {
                registrado = true;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (registrado = true) {
            this.usuarios.remove(usuario);
        } else {
            System.out.println("El usuario no existe.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que tienes **varios** errores de concepto en tu código que indican que no has entendido cómo funcionan los operadores condicionales en Java. Ejemplo: `while (i < this.usuarios.size() & !registrado) {
` y también: `if (registrado = true) {` sería bueno que [revises esto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) en la documentación.

Answer (score 3):

En el método `altaUsuario`, tienes esto:

```
if (registrado = false) {
    this.usuarios.add(usuario);
    //...
}
```

Lo que haces allí es:

1. Asignar el valor `false` a la variable `registrado`.
2. Tu bloque `if` evalúa `false`, por ende nunca va a registrar el elemento en el `Vector` (que debería ser `List`).

Además, tienes un problema en el ciclo `while` anterior. Una vez que has encontrado que el usuario ya está registrado, deberías cortar el loop, de lo contrario continuará una ejecución más y la variable cambiará su valor a `false`. Aquí:

```
while (i < this.usuarios.size() & !registrado) {
    if (this.usuarios.get(i).getDni().equals(usuario.getDni())) {
        registrado = true;
        //aquí aplica un break
    }
    i++;
}
```

El código completo debería ser:

```
public void altaUsuario(Free usuario) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean registrado = false;

    while (i < this.usuarios.size() & !registrado) {
        if (this.usuarios.get(i).getDni().equals(usuario.getDni())) {
            registrado = true;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (!registrado) {
        this.usuarios.add(usuario);
        System.out.println("Usuario añadido.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("El usuario ya está registrado.");
    }

}
```

---

Nota a lectores:
No voté a cierre la pregunta porque el problema no solo está en el `if` sino también por el otro issue del ciclo `while`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no he conseguido resolverlo del todo pero parece que ya estoy más cerca.

Answer (score 0):

Estás utilizando el operador de asignación "=" en lugar del comparador "==" en tu sentencia condicional, lo que provoca que nunca se cumpla la condición. Lo mismo ocurre con tu operador "AND", ya que utilizas el operador binario "&" en lugar de "&&".

Donde pones

```
while (i < this.usuarios.size() & !registrado) {
    ...
}

if (registrado = false) {
    ...
}
```

debería poner

```
while (i < this.usuarios.size() && !registrado) {
    ...
}
if (registrado == false) {
    ...
}
```

o, idealmente

```
if (!registrado) {
    ...
}
```